# Project reactor: onErrorResume after flatMap

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

```
Flux.just("a", "b")
        .flatMap(s -> s.equals("a") ? Mono.error(new RuntimeException() : Flux.just(s + "1", s + "2"))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Hello!

Here I made a flux of two elements and then expose by flatMap first one to exception, and second one to another Flux.

With `onErrorResume` I expect the output

```
b1
b2
```

but get nothing. Could anyone explain why does it happens, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given this:

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
        .flatMap { s ->
            if (s == "b") 
                Mono.error<RuntimeException>(RuntimeException()) 
            else 
                Flux.just(s + "1", s + "2")
        }.onErrorResume { throwable -> Mono.just("d") }.log()
        .subscribe { println(it) }
```

The output is:

```
12:35:19.673 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.ResumeSubscriber)
12:35:19.676 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - request(unbounded)
12:35:19.677 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - onNext(a1)
a1
12:35:19.677 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - onNext(a2)
a2
12:35:19.712 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - onNext(d)
d
12:35:19.713 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - onComplete()
```

What's going on here? `onErrorResume()` **is being applied to the Publisher returned by the `flatMap()` operator**. Since on "b" the Publisher signals a failure, the  `flatMap()` Publisher doesn't execute anymore and `onErrorResume()` operator keeps publishing using its fallback.

The [documentation for onErrorResume()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorResume-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Function-) shows clearly that the original Publisher finishes because of the error and the fallback takes over:

[image]

Comment: Hey, to get the output what he expects ie to get b1, b2 as output, cant we use onErrorReturn()? How can we achieve that otherwise?

Comment: @uneq95 have a look at my complementary answer.

Answer (score 6):

This question has already a solid answer by `codependent` why this happens. To answer a little off-topic **how to achieve the expected output**:

The `onErrorResume` call has to be moved into the `flatMap`:

```
Flux.just("a", "b")
    .flatMap(s ->
        (s.equals("a") ? Mono.error<RuntimeException>(RuntimeException()) : Flux.just(s + "1", s + "2"))
             .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.empty())
    )
    .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

This way the output is as expected

```
b1
b2
```